# Open Windows Registry Editor from excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, regedit

I want to open the default registry editor with a specific registry key opened when I click on a command button in a excel worksheet. Is there anyway I can do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `regedit.exe` do not allow opening itself with a specified key. If you only need to read a key value, you can use VBA `Windows Scripting Feature` to do it:

```
Dim myWS As Object
Dim i_RegKey As String
'Change this with your Registry Key
i_RegKey = "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Control Panel\Accessibility\HighContrast\Flags"

On Error Resume Next
'Access Windows scripting
Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Read key from registry
RegKeyRead = myWS.RegRead(i_RegKey)
'Do something with this value
```

Otherwise, if you need to read it with `regedit.exe`, you can download a Microsoft tool called `regjump.exe` and setting it to jump to your specified key. More info on how to do that [here](https://superuser.com/questions/115854/open-registry-directly-to-a-given-key).

Hope this helps.